# Populating a list of integers in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, list, integer

I need a list of integers from 1 to x where x is set by the user.  I could build it with a for loop eg assuming x is an integer set previously:

```
List<int> iList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
{
    iList.Add(i);
}
```

This seems dumb, surely there's a more elegant way to do this, something like the [PHP range method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Comment: `Enumerable.Range` is elegant but is slightly slower than a simple loop. May be relevant in some scenarios.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you're using .Net 3.5, [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) is what you need.

> Generates a sequence of integral
>   numbers within a specified range.

Comment: This will return an IEnumerable<int>, not a List<int>, so like aku noted, you'll want to call .ToList() on the Enumerable.Range(x,y) call.

Comment: its generally better to use IEnumerable<> wherever possible for fullest flexibility. especially if this list doesnt change it most likely neednt be a generic List<T>

Comment: Why is a range method more elegant than just doing a simple for loop with the conditional being the max?

Comment: IMHO it is quite evident that var List = new List<int>(Max - Min); for (var Index = Min; Index < Max; ++Index) List.Add(Index); is not elegant as Enumerable.Range(Min, Max);

Answer (score 63):

LINQ to the rescue:

```
// Adding value to existing list
var list = new List<int>();
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, x));

// Creating new list
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, x).ToList();
```

See [Generation Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336752.aspx#range) on [LINQ 101](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

Answer (score 20):

I'm one of many who has [blogged](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/04/project-euler-problem-4.html) about a ruby-esque *To* extension method that you can write if you're using C#3.0:

```
public static class IntegerExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> To(this int first, int last)
    {
        for (int i = first; i <= last; i++)

        { 
            yield return i;
        } 
    }
}
```

Then you can create your list of integers like this

```
List<int> = first.To(last).ToList();
```

or

```
List<int> = 1.To(x).ToList();
```

Comment: The other answers are more likely what the questioner was looking for, but I voted up here because I like the resulting syntax.  How much more readable can you get than "1.To(10)"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short method that returns a List of integers.

```
    public static List<int> MakeSequence(int startingValue, int sequenceLength)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(startingValue, sequenceLength).ToList<int>();
    }
```