# Easier way to populate a list with integers in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populating a list of integers in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214/populating-a-list-of-integers-in-net)

Is there a simpler or more elegant way of initializing a list of integers in C# other than this?

```
List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

or

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    numberList.Add(i);
}
```

It just doesn't seem very practical - especially if the list was to contain a large number of values. Would a loop be a more practical solution?

Thanks,

CC

Comment: the *FIRST* entry in the "Related" Section discusses exactly this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214/populating-a-list-of-integers-in-net

Comment: This means you are all voting on a question that has been answered *more than two years ago*.

Comment: As an aside - you don't need the () after declaring the List<int>

Comment: And yes..two years ago the answer was *use Enumerable.Range*.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var numberList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
```

The first parameter is the integer to start at and the second parameter is how many sequential integers to include.

Comment: Linq will work with _any_ .NET language, VB.NET included.

Comment: I'm *so* tempted to whack in a `var` there too ;p

Comment: I didn't know that LINQ was even capable of stuff like this - I always thought it was mainly for SQL-related queries... Thanks!

Comment: @TheCodingCowboy "LINQ" stands for Language INtegrated Query. There are a bunch of forms of LINQ -- LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL (deprecated), LINQ to Entities, LINQ to XML. It's just a set of extension methods for fluently querying objects.

Comment: @DanielMann: No, LINQ is [an SQL-like syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397897.aspx).  Few people use it, almost everyone just calls the extension methods directly, to the point where people have even forgotten that the query syntax exists.  This answer doesn't use LINQ, and `Range` isn't an extension method (`ToList` is).

Answer (score 48):

If your initialization list is as simple as a consecutive sequence of values from `from` to `end`, you can just say

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(from, end - from + 1)
                        .ToList();
```

If your initialization list is something a little more intricate that can be defined by a mapping `f` from `int` to `int`, you can say

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(from, end - from + 1)
                        .Select(n => f(n))
                        .ToList();
```

For example:

```
var primes = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                       .Select(n => Prime(n))
                       .ToList();
```

would generate the first ten primes assuming that `Prime` is a `Func<int, int>` that takes an `int n` and returns the `n`th prime.

Comment: It does provides a major difference, for when the starting of the range is not 0 but anythign greater than zero.