# C# Instantiate List by Calling a Function

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a more minimal way to write the following:

```
var voucherCodes = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    voucherCodes.Add(GenerateCode(VoucherCodeLength));
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
// ten items would be added to the list so long as GenerateCode returns a string
var voucherCodes = new List<string>(GenerateCode(VoucherCodeLength), 10);
```

Granted, I could create my own function, but I was wondering if there was something that already exists.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926362/easier-way-to-populate-a-list-with-integers-in-net

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(n => GenerateCode(VoucherCodeLength)).ToList();`

Comment: What's wrong with current implementation? It works, it's readable, it's short.

Comment: @Dennis Fair question.  I think it's good to reduce code when possible.  If something as readable as `Enumerable.Range()` exists, then I might as well use it over creating my own function or using a for loop, is my opinion.

Comment: @Dennis Personally I prefer the one-liner in this particular case, but I agree the original isn't bad or anything. Matter of taste. Maybe OP likes one-liners too. Some one-liners are a horrorshow; this is OK IMO.

Comment: Well, you're using `Range` as a replacement for regular `for` loop. IMO, this smells in the same way as List.Foreach does. But this is a matter of taste, agree.

Comment: @Dennis I wonder if there's really a broadly accepted meaning for "code smell"; "not the way I'd do it, myself" doesn't qualify as anything inherently objectionable. If it's a useful term it means something more like "red flag": business logic in event handlers, for example, or `listBox.Add()` in a WPF project, or `scanf` in a SO question. One of those things where your heart sinks and you say "oh, boy, this'll be an ugly one...". `Enumerable.Range().Select()` may not be your bag, but it's not a reliable indicator of awful code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say if it's better, but you can use the folloing LINQ "one-liner":

```
var voucherCodes = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => GenerateCode(VoucherCodeLength)).ToList();
```

or specifically for this call, and if the `VoucherCodeLength` is constant (or does not change and has no side effects), an even shorter:

```
var voucherCodes = Enumerable.Repeat(VoucherCodeLength, 10).Select(GenerateCode).ToList();
```

Comment: I like this approach.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Another linqy way

```
var voucherCodes = Enumerable.Repeat(GenerateCode(VoucherCodeLength), 10).ToList();
```

Comment: This has the same defect as (currently deleted) answer by @InBetween

Comment: @IvanStoev I read it now, but  since question is not clear, i will leave the answer for now...