# Adding multiple copies of an item to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have an POCO object and based on the number input I want to copy this object into the list of this object type. Is there an elegant way, other than using a loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating a list of integers in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214/populating-a-list-of-integers-in-net)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(item, count));
```

**Example:**

```
var list = new List<int>();

list.Add(0); // 0
list.Add(1); // 0, 1
list.Add(2); // 0, 1, 2

var item = 5;
var count = 3;

list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(item, count)); // 0, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5
```

**Note:**

For reference objects, this will add the same object x times.
If you want to create a new object x times and add, you can do:

```
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, count).Select(x => new MyObject()));
```